# No body in POST request

Tags: json, node.js, server

I'm working on a web-push notifications project. I want to send user subscriptions from my client to a node server.

**Client side code**

```
function sendSubscriptionToBackEnd(subscription) {
  return fetch('/api/save-subscription/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(subscription)
  });
}
```

**Server side code**

```
app.post('/api/save-subscription/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
}
```

The subscription object is a standard subscription with "endpoint" and "keys". I have already tried printing the subscription on the client side before sending it and it appears to be valid.

The problem is that the "req" object on the server side doesn't contain any "body" key. So, I don't know how to grab the subscription on the server side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might need the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware if you don't have it already.

That's what parses the body of http requests, and gives you a nice parsed object to deal with.

In your server side code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // <-- this guy!

app.post('/api/save-subscription', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  return res.sendStatus(201);
});
```

Comment: We were all new at one point - best of luck with your learning!